# Insert/update multiple objects

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following class:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CarId { get; set; } 
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; } 
}
```

And a view:

```
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(location => location.Description)</div>
    <div>@Html.EditorFor(location => location.Description)</div>

    <div>@Html.LabelFor(location => location.Car.Id)</div>
    <div>@Html.EditorFor(location => location.Car.Id)</div>

    <div>@Html.LabelFor(location => location.Car.Color)</div>
    <div>@Html.EditorFor(location => location.Car.Color)</div>
```

When i try this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Location location)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            Car car = db.Car.Find(location.Car.Id);

            if (car != null)
                db.Entry(car).CurrentValues.SetValues(location.Car);
            else
                db.Car.Add(location.Car);

            db.Location.Add(locacao);
            db.SaveChanges();  

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(locacao);
    }
```

it breaks in 'db.SaveChanges' cause it says 'Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Car'.'

If I remove 'db.Location.Add(locacao);', so it works pretty fine for the car(insert and update), but no location is added in database.

How can I do to insert a new car when there is not car's id in database, update when there is, and insert a new location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add` method always adds all entities in the object graph so both `db.Car.Add(location.Car)` and `db.Location.Add(location)` are inserting both location and car.

Try this:

```
db.Location.Add(locacation);
// You can also use another way to find if you are working with a new Car 
// like location.Car.Id == 0
if (db.Car.Any(c => c.Id == location.Car.Id)) 
{
    db.Entry(location.Car).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```